# getJson only working once in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

I am currently working on a small random Quote Generator (Freecodecamp Project) with codepen.io. You can find it here: http://codepen.io/Baumo/pen/VjQbBj?editors=1000

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#getQuote').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          url: 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1',
            success: function(a) {
            $(".quote").html(a[0].content + "<p>&mdash; " + a[0].title + "</p>");
          }
        });
     });
  });  
</script>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="message quote">

    </div>
    <div class = "right">
      <button class="btn" id="getQuote">
        NEW QUOTE
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If I open the page with Microsoft Edge, it works just fine. But in Google Chrome the "New Quote" Button will only work the first time I click it.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is aggressively caching your ajax requests.  Add `cache: false` to the request:

```
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1',
      cache: false,
        success: function(a) {
        $(".quote").html(a[0].content + "<p>&mdash; " + a[0].title + "</p>");
      }
    });
```